# react-native-webrtc Mic not closing after video call on iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, webrtc, voip

**Our iOS app has audio video calling implemented using the following technologies:**

1. `"react-native": "0.63.4"`
2. `"react": "16.13.1"`
3. `"react-native-webrtc": "^1.87.3"`
4. `"react-native-incall-manager": "^3.3.0"`
5. iOS version `14.4.1`

**Our calling module works like the following:**

1. First request and initiate audio call
2. Then request and initiate video call

**On the code side things work like this:**

1. We call the `getStream()` function which gets the user media for audio call i.e Audio only
2. Then we call the `startStream()` function which connects the peer connection
3. On requesting video we call the `getVideoStream()` method to get Audio and Video streams
4. Call `startStream()` again to start peer connection with video

**The scenario is as follows:**

1. We start off by connecting an audio call. On success the audio call is connected and works fine as expected
2. We request for video and connect video call, all works fine as expected and I receive video on both ends
3. When I disconnect the call and stop tracks using `this.state.localStream.getTracks()`, the mic does not close. An orange indicator for mic is visible on iOS.

**Important Notes:**

1. Disconnecting from the audio call closes the mic just fine
2. Even if we get video stream on audio call and disconnect without connecting video it still works fine and closes both tracks
3. Its only when I connect the video is when the issue arises
4. Calling `InCallManager.stop()` closes the mic but does not open it on second call. The mic does not open on second call and the orange mic indicator on iOS is not shown.

**Get User Media Audio Call**

```
getStream() {
    InCallManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
    InCallManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);

    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((sourceInfos) => {

      let videoSourceId;

      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (
          sourceInfo.kind === 'videoinput' &&
          sourceInfo.facing === (true ? 'front' : 'back')
        ) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
        }
      }
      mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          this.setState({
            localStream: stream,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Log error
          console.log('stream get error', error);
        });
    });
  }
```

**Get User Media for Video Call**

```
getVideoStream() {
    this.state.peerConn.removeStream(this.state.localStream);
    InCallManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
    InCallManager.setMicrophoneMute(false);

    mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then((sourceInfos) => {

      let videoSourceId;

      for (let i = 0; i < sourceInfos.length; i++) {
        const sourceInfo = sourceInfos[i];
        if (
          sourceInfo.kind === 'videoinput' &&
          sourceInfo.facing === (true ? 'front' : 'back')
        ) {
          videoSourceId = sourceInfo.deviceId;
        }
      }
      mediaDevices
        .getUserMedia({
          audio: true,
          mirror: true,
          video: {
            mandatory: {
              minWidth: 500,
              minHeight: 300,
              minFrameRate: 30,
            },
            facingMode: true ? 'user' : 'environment',
            optional: videoSourceId ? [{sourceId: videoSourceId}] : [],
          },
        })
        .then((stream) => {
          this.setState(
            {
              localStream: stream,
            },
            () => {
              this.startStream();
            },
          );
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Log error
          console.log('stream get error', error);
        });
    });
  }
```

**Start Stream Function**

```
startStream() {
    console.log('start Stream');

    this.newPeerConnection();

    setTimeout(() => {
      this.state.peerConn
        .createOffer()
        .then((sessionDescription) =>
          this.setLocalAndSendMessage(sessionDescription),
        )
        .catch((error) => this.defaultErrorCallback(error));
    }, 3000);
  }
```

**newPeerConnection()**

```
newPeerConnection() {
    var peerConn = new RTCPeerConnection({
      iceServers: turnServer,
    });


    peerConn.onicecandidate = (evt) => {

      console.log(`OnIceCan`);
      if (evt.candidate) {
        this.state.connection.invoke(
          'addIceCandidate',
          parseInt(this.state.ticket.pkTicketId),
          JSON.stringify({
            type: 'candidate',
            sdpMLineIndex: evt.candidate.sdpMLineIndex,
            sdpMid: evt.candidate.sdpMid,
            candidate: evt.candidate.candidate,
          }),
        );
      }
    };

    peerConn.addStream(this.state.localStream);

    peerConn.addEventListener(
      'addstream',
      (stream) => {

        InCallManager.setForceSpeakerphoneOn(false);
        this.setState({
          isSpeakerEnabled: false,
        });

        this.setState({
          remoteStream: stream,
          showAudioCallTimer: true,
        });
      },
      false,
    );

    this.setState(
      {
        peerConn,
      });
  }
```

**Close Tracks**

```
if (this.state.localStream) {
          const tracks = this.state.localStream.getTracks();

          tracks.map((track, index) => {
            track.stop();
          });
        }
        if (this.state.peerConn) {
          this.state.peerConn.removeStream(this.state.localStream);
          this.state.peerConn.close();
          if (!this.state.callRatingSubmitted && this.state.remoteStream) {
            this._handleCallFeedbackModal(true);
          }
        }
```

Comment: is your only problem mic?

Comment: For us, it was the peer connection -- we weren't destroying/closing it correctly.

Comment: u need to close all local peerConnection, release it